# SideBar vertical menu: item collapses when sub-item is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigationbar

I have a sidebar menu with a nested list system with three nesting levels. Initially only level-1 list items are visible. On clicking level-1 li, level-2 is displayed and similarly for level-2 li. However, due the jquery logic I have used, on clicking a sub-item in level-2(which is a child of level-1 li) the level-1 li event gets triggered and the sub-item menu is hidden once again. The code is given below -

HTML:

```
<ul class="level-1">
    <li>
        Category
        <ul class="level-2">
            <li>
                <div class="arrow"></div>
                Sub 1
                <ul class="level-3">
                    <li>
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                        Sub 2
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                        Sub 2
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="arrow"></div>
                Sub 1
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="arrow"></div>
                Sub 1
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.categories ul{
    margin:10%;
}
.categories ul li{
    font-size: 2.5vh;
    font-family: "Droid Sans";
    margin:0 0 5% 0;
}
.categories ul > li:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color:orange;
}
.categories ul li ul li{
    font-size:2vh;
    margin:0 0 5% 0;
}
.categories ul li ul li .arrow{
    width: 5%;
    border: none;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5% 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 5% 0 10%;
    float: left;
}
.categories ul li ul li ul li{
    font-size: 1.8vh;
}
.categories ul li ul li ul li .arrow{
    width:2%;
    padding:2% 0 0 0;
    margin:0 2% 0 30%;
}
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.level-2').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('.level-3').toggleClass('hidden');
});

$(".level-1 li").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".level-2").toggleClass("hidden");
});

$(".level-2 li").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".level-3").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/SpiderWasp42/t65k4kc8/

Please suggest a way to get around this problem. Cheers

Comment: your jsfiddle not related to above codes

Comment: sorry about that. I have updated the link. You can check it now.

Comment: In your code I can see a two nesting level menu and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you click the `.level-2 li` you're also triggering the `.level-1 li` click because the `.level-2` elements are contained inside the `.level-1`.  You either need to not use `toggleClass` and be more explicit about using `addClass` and `removeClass` as appropriate (by checking parent states and child states and such).  Or you can add a `stopPropagation` call which will stop the event from bubbling  once it's been handled.

I tried the following in your fiddle and it seems to do the trick.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.level-2. .level-3').toggleClass('hidden');
});
$(".level-1 li").click(function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find(".level-2").toggleClass("hidden");
});
$(".level-2 li").click(function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find(".level-3").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```